# Using XPath, select node without text sibling

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml.html

I want to extract some HTML elements with python3 and the HTML parser provided by lxml.

Consider this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <span class="foo">
      <span class="bar">bar</span>
      foo
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Consider this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring('html from above')
bars = tree.xpath("//span[@class='bar']")
print(bars)
print(html.tostring(bars[0], encoding="unicode"))
```

In a browser, the query selector "span.bar" selects only the span element. This is what I desire. However, the above program produces:

```
[<Element span at 0x7f5dd89a4048>]
<span class="bar">bar</span>foo
```

It looks like my XPath does not actually behave like a query selector and the sibling text node is picked up next to the span element. How can I adjust the XPath to select only the bar element, but not the text "foo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that XML tree model in `lxml` (as well as in the standard module `xml.etree`) has concept of `tail`. So text nodes *located after* a.k.a *`following-sibling` of* element will be stored as `tail` of that element. So your XPath correctly return the `span` element, but according to the tree model, it has `tail` which holds the text 'foo'.

As a workaround, assuming that you don't want to use the tree model further, simply clear the `tail` before printing:

```
>>> bars[0].tail = ''
>>> print(html.tostring(bars[0], encoding="unicode"))
<span class="bar">bar</span>
```

Comment: The notion of a `tail` annoyingly clashes with normal XML and XPath based expectations, but this is a very helpful answer.